# Where to execute kube-proxy command?

Tags: kubernetes

From [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/) article, I can specify 'userspace' as my proxy-mode, but I am unable to understand what command I need to use for it and at what stage? Like after creating deployment or service? 
I am running a minikube cluster currently.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make kube-proxy use userspace mode instead of ip tables

Comment: You can change the proxy mode in kubeconfig.conf which store in the configmap, `kubectl get cm -n kube-system kube-proxy -o yaml`, check the key 'mode'. You can switch between iptables and ipvs, not sure whether userspace works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`kube-proxy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/) is a process that runs on each kubernetes node to [manage network connections coming into and out of kubernetes](https://supergiant.io/blog/understanding-kubernetes-kube-proxy/).

You don't run the command as such, but your deployment method (usually kubeadm) configures the options for it to run.

As @Hang Du mentioned, in minikube you can modify it's options by editing the `kube-proxy` configmap and changing `mode` to `userspace`

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap kube-proxy
```

Then delete the Pod.

```
kubectl -n kube-system get pod
kubectl -n kube-system delete pod kube-proxy-XXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using minikube, you can find a `DaemonSet` named `kube-proxy` like followings:

```
$ kubectl get ds -n kube-system kube-proxy -o yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  ...
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-proxy
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
  ...
spec:
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
        - --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
        - --hostname-override=$(NODE_NAME)
        env:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.15.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kube-proxy
   ...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/kube-proxy
          name: kube-proxy
        - mountPath: /run/xtables.lock
          name: xtables-lock
        - mountPath: /lib/modules
          name: lib-modules
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      ...
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: kube-proxy
        name: kube-proxy
      - hostPath:
          path: /run/xtables.lock
          type: FileOrCreate
        name: xtables-lock
      - hostPath:
          path: /lib/modules
          type: ""
        name: lib-modules
  ...
```

Look at the `.spec.template.spec.containers[].command`, the container runs the `kube-proxy` command. You can provide the flag `--proxy-mode=userspace` in the command array.

```
- command:
  - /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
  - --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
  - --hostname-override=$(NODE_NAME)
  - --proxy-mode=userspace
```